# How to fix Fragment is not an active fragment Error

Tags: android, fragment

I have a problem switching between fragments using my bottom navigation view.it loads first and i can switch between the fragments for the first time but if a fragment was already loaded and try to navigate back to it. My app crashes showing an error i listed below.

Here is my code

```
private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
        when (it.itemId) {

            R.id.vegetables -> {
                showFragment(VegetablesFragment(),VegetablesFragment().javaClass.simpleName)return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }

            R.id.fruits -> {
                showFragment(FruitsFragment(),FruitsFragment().javaClass.simpleName)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }

            R.id.grocery -> {
                showFragment(GroceryFragment(),GroceryFragment().javaClass.simpleName)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }

            else -> return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener false
        }
    }
```

```
private fun showFragment(fragment : Fragment ,fragmentName :String) {
    val transaction = manager.beginTransaction()
    val currentFragment = manager.primaryNavigationFragment
       if (currentFragment != null) {
           transaction.hide(currentFragment)
       }
       val fragmentTemp = manager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentName)

       if (fragmentTemp == null){
           transaction.add(R.id.fragmentHolder,fragment,fragmentName)
           Log.d("ac1001","case 2")
       } else {
           Log.d("ac1001","case 1")
           transaction.show(fragment)
       }

     transaction.setPrimaryNavigationFragment(fragment)
     transaction.setReorderingAllowed(true)
     transaction.commitNowAllowingStateLoss()
    }
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fragment VegetablesFragment{d4a075d (f9739b50-c0fc-47c1-80d1-dc413ffd5a09)} is not an active fragment of FragmentManager FragmentManager{5b1a8d2 in HostCallbacks{2810da3}}
```

I tried searching everywhere but couldn't find an answer.

The error is occuring on my transaction.show(..)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code.  change your showFragment function to ->

```
fun showFragment(fragment: Fragment ,fragmentName :String) {
    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentHolder, fragment)
    transaction.addToBackStack(fragmentName)
    transaction.commit()
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I need to use show/hide not replace i posed my fix below.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing my code to:

```
private fun showFragment(fragment : Fragment ,fragmentName :String) {
           val transaction = manager.beginTransaction()
           val currentFragment = manager.primaryNavigationFragment
           if (currentFragment != null) {
               transaction.hide(currentFragment)
           }
           val fragmentTemp = manager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentName)

           if (fragmentTemp == null){
               transaction.add(R.id.fragmentHolder,fragment,fragmentName)
           } else {
               transaction.show(fragmentTemp)
           }

           transaction.setPrimaryNavigationFragment(fragmentTemp)
           transaction.setReorderingAllowed(true)
           transaction.commitNowAllowingStateLoss()
       }
```